# MySQL Left Join and Right Join Optimization

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I've been looking up some documentation about this topic here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html

But I don't understand the following example:

> The join optimizer calculates the order in which to join tables. The table read order forced by LEFT JOIN or STRAIGHT_JOIN helps the join optimizer do its work much more quickly, because there are fewer table permutations to check. This means that if you execute a query of the following type, MySQL does a full scan on b because the LEFT JOIN forces it to be read before d:

`SELECT *
  FROM a JOIN b LEFT JOIN c ON (c.key=a.key)
  LEFT JOIN d ON (d.key=a.key)
  WHERE b.key=d.key;`

> The fix in this case is reverse the order in which a and b are listed in the FROM clause:

`SELECT *
  FROM b JOIN a LEFT JOIN c ON (c.key=a.key)
  LEFT JOIN d ON (d.key=a.key)
  WHERE b.key=d.key;`

Why does the order make an optimization? Do JOIN and LEFT_JOIN execute in some order?

Comment: no Join in mysql would be a natural join (joining on same named fields).  However since the join to c is on c.key = a.key in order to resolve this the SQL engine must first join a and b and resolve carnality.  By reversing the order the engine is able to join directly a to c w/o going though b.  [I think based on several years of DB exp]

Comment: In most situations, the Optimizer freely picks between `a` and `b` in `FROM a JOIN b`.  The `WHERE` conditions (if any) and the size of those tables seems to be the main criteria.  So, I am surprised by what is being said in this Question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the first quote is not quite correct.  I have seen `LEFT JOIN` turned into `JOIN` and then the tables touched in the 'wrong' order.

Anyway, don't worry about the work the optimizer needs to do.  In thousands of slow `JOINs`, I have identified only one case where the cost of picking the order was important.  And it was a case of multiple joins to a single table; yet another drawback of EAV schema.  Anyway, there is a simple setting to avoid that problem.

`LEFT/RIGHT/plain JOINs` are *semantically* done left-to-right (regardless of the order the optimizer chooses to touch the tables).

If you are concerned about the ordering, you can add parentheses.  For example:

```
FROM (a JOIN b ON ...) JOIN (c JOIN d ON ...) ON ...
```

If you are using "commajoin" (`FROM a,b...`), don't.  However, its precedence changed long ago.  The workaround was to add parens so that the same SQL would work in versions before *and* after the change.

Don't use `LEFT` unless you need it to get `NULLs` for missing 'right' rows.  It just confuses readers into thinking that you expect `NULLs`.

Answer (score 1):

This example is wrong in many ways, and it is not clear to me what it is trying to convey.  Apologies for that.  I will file a bug with the documentation team.

Some clarifications:

1. For the given query, the last LEFT JOIN will be converted to an inner join.  This is because the WHERE clause, WHERE b.key=d.key, implies that d.key can not be NULL.  Hence, any extra rows produced by LEFT JOIN compared to INNER JOIN would be filtered out by the WHERE clause.  (The principles of this transformation is described in the paragraph following the given example.)
2. The ON clause of the first LEFT JOIN, ON (c.key=a.key), makes table c dependent on table a, but not table b.  Hence, the only the requirement wrt join order is that table a is processed before table c.  The order in which tables a and b are listed in the query, will not change that.
3. Tables b and d may be processed in any order, both wrt each other and wrt the other tables of the query.
4. This paragraph seems to recommend LEFT JOIN as a mechanism to reduce number of "table permutations to check".  This is not meaningful since changing from INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN may change the semantics of the query.  For this purpose STRAIGHT_JOIN should be used instead.
5. For most join queries, execution time by far exceeds optimization time.  Reducing the number of "table permutations to check" may cause potentially more efficient permutations to not be explored.  Hence, LEFT JOIN should not be used unless it is required to get the wanted semantics.